# How can I see a list of apps that have the ability to record my keyboard history?

Tags: security

How can I see a list of programs/services that have the ability to record my keyboard history? My goal is to prevent programs from recording my keyboard history without root privilege. I cannot seem to find any Apple's documentation on its security policies. References are also appreciated.

Comment: What makes you assume that there is such a list? Are you also concerned about keyboard recording done by any application you are using?

Comment: @patrix I thought OS X's security policy will demand some sort of authorization for accessing keyboard; if so, there is certainly a log showing these authorizations. And yes I am.

Comment: Accepting keyboard input is so basic that I doubt that applications need special rights to do so (but I've been wrong before, so let's see whether somebody has an answer here). But if an application is legitimately processing your keystrokes (think Mail or Pages) I doubt that any OS-side functionality can tell you whether the application also keeps a history of all keypresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Apps which are in the foreground are granted access to the keyboard automatically.
- Apps which are run by your user account but are not in the foreground require accessibility access to access the keyboard. The list of applications granted access to this is available in **System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Accessibility**. Here you can add and remove applications to grant and deny access, however some applications may lose functionality.
- Apps which run as root are not restricted in this way. You will have been required to authorise this before this is permitted. You can check the current list of running root processes in Activity Monitor.

Keep in mind there's no keyboard *history* maintained — the apps must be recording it live.